# SQLite exception: Database is locked issue

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, locking

I'm having an issue with my SQLite database inside an Android app. It seems to happen every so often and I cannot reproduce it, but this is the report the Android Market gives.

Basically I have first a splash screen activity that starts by checking if all the needed data is in the database. If not, it will install the data in a asynchronous thread and close the db connection.

Then and only then can the main activity be started, which also opens and reads/writes the database.

This code is executed from the onCreate method of the splash screen activity:

```
dbWord = new WordDBAdapter(this, myUI);
dbWord.open();
if (dbWord.isDataInstalled()) {
    dbWord.close();
    databaseInstalled = true;
    clickToStartView.setText(myUI.PRESS_TO_START);
    clickToStartView.startAnimation(myBlinkAnim);
} else {
    // If not, try to install in asynchronous thread
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setMessage(myUI.INSTALLING_DB);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    new InstallDBData().execute("");
}
```

The code for the asynchronous thread is:

```
private class InstallDBData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        dbWord.installData(0, getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setProgress(20);
        dbWord.installData(1, getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setProgress(40);
        dbWord.installData(2, getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setProgress(60);
        dbWord.installData(3, getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setProgress(80);
        dbWord.installData(4, getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setProgress(100);
        return 1;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer x) {
        dbWord.close();
        progressDialog.hide();
        databaseInstalled = true;
        clickToStartView.setText(myUI.PRESS_TO_START);
        clickToStartView.startAnimation(myBlinkAnim);
    }
}
```

These are important parts of the WordDBAdapter class, which is also used by the main activity:

```
public class WordDBAdapter {
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public WordDBAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm getting the following exceptions, which are similar but have a different message:

First type of error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{example.flashcards.medical/com.example.flashcards.common.SplashWindow}: 
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
....
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1870)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionWithListener(SQLiteDatabase.java:602)
```

Second type of error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{example.flashcards.medical/com.example.flashcards.common.SplashWindow}: 
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
....
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1987)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1855)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
```

I would really like to not have to create a ContentProvider, because I believe its overkill if a simpler solution is available. Also, only this application has access to the database.

Any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 19):

After doing some effort I did it (My app was working on perfect till android 2.3 but got db lock error when I used to run it on HoneyComb tablet).
I did using Semaphores (using lock in critical sections).

**Example 1**

```
public class DbExp extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static String Lock = "dblock";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";

    public void delete(Context mContext){
        synchronized(Lock) {
            SQLiteDatabase db  = getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public void insert(){
        synchronized(Lock) {
            SQLiteDatabase db  = getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, ..., ...);
            db.close();
        }
    }

}
```

**Example 2**

```
public class DB {
    public static String Lock = "dblock";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";

    public void delete(Context mContext){
        synchronized(Lock) {
            SQLiteDatabase db  = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public void insert(Context mContext){
        synchronized(Lock) {
            SQLiteDatabase db  = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, ..., ...);
            db.close();
        }
    }


}
```

Hope this would help Anyone in future :)

Comment: I used this way for my application database access But not working in my case please have a look at my question [link is here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859840/application-crashes-on-installation-with-error-sqlite3-exec-failed-to-set-sync)

Answer (score 5):

If your using Fragments and it happens with orientation changes, its because you have two instances of the same Fragment and they both have their own instance of a Db helper class of some kind. In order to make it work you either have to destroy your fragment on orientation change and rebuild it, or find a way to destroy the Db helper class. This is only for Fragments with orientation issues. I had to do alot of troubleshooting to figure it out, so hopefully someone finds this helpful

Answer (score 5):

This was the Reason for me:

I forgot to end transaction in my function call after inserting into db .So when i tried to insert another record from another activity i got database locked exception. Adding the below statement solved my issue.

```
sqlDB.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Awesome. i've been strugulling with this for hours... you just save my day bro.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to close your DB in the main thread and open and close it in your doInBackground method:

```
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
        db.open();
        try {
        // your code here
        } finally {
            db.close()
        }            
        return 1;
    }
```

Also you should not directly call UI methods from AsyncTask as UI is not thread safe. Instead call method updateProgress from doInBackground and update your progressDialog from onProgressUpdate as onProgressUpdate is called from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an older question, but maybe this will help someone.  I was having the same issue, I was loading probably around a dozen tables in one database and would regularly crash, not always, but sometimes.

Finally, and this may be hackey, I just created a separate database for each table.  So now I have a dozen databases, each with one table.  But, no more exceptions.  Code was sounds, was creating, opening and closing correctly, just seemed to be getting collisions somewhere.

Like I said you may consider it hackey, but it fixed my issue.

db

Comment: Be aware that you won't be able to create transactions involving tables in separate databases with this approach.

Comment: Using one database per table defeats so many purposes of having a relational database, such as performing joins or having transactions across many tables.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is because you havn't properly opened or created database. give it a try if this is the case.

```
mDb = mCtx.openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseName, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
```

in the DatabaseHelper Class:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context aContext)
{       
    mDb = aContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseName, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);    
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(aContext, mDb );     
    mDb = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Where would this go? Inside public WordDBAdapter open() ?

Comment: i have done it in constructor of my DatabaseHelper class. I edit my answer for you.

Comment: Are you sure this is needed? From the Android docs regarding SQLiteOpenHelper: "You create a subclass implementing onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and optionally onOpen(SQLiteDatabase), and this class takes care of opening the database if it exists, creating it if it does not, and upgrading it as necessary. Transactions are used to make sure the database is always in a sensible state." My DatabaseHelper class extends SQLiteOpenHelper so opening and creating if needed should be covered, right?

Comment: Khawar, I noticed you're not calling `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);` within the DatabaseHelper() constructor

Comment: @Khawar doesn't care tho

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code resolved my (the same) problem:

(I had my transaction opened before...)

```
writableDatabase.endTransaction();
writableDatabase.close();
dbHelper.close();
```