# Concurrency issues in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, concurrency, locking, android-asynctask

I am having issues when I am running an AsyncTask that performs a long delete action on the local SQLite database. If the user rotates the screen, then the Activity is recreated and a new connection to the database is created, while the AsyncTask is running.

I know that SQLite supports multiple reading and one writing at a time, and this will be the case, so **I do not understand why it crashes when opening the database as readable while deleting is done...**

The failure is the next:

```
04-26 12:54:21.839: I/Database(3925): sqlite returned: error code = 5, msg = database is locked
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925): SELECT locale FROM android_metadata failed
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925): Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1967)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1835)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:197)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:172)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(DatabaseManager.java:180)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.open(DatabaseManager.java:157)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.persistence.DatabaseManager.<init>(DatabaseManager.java:147)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.openerp.models.ConnectionProfile$ConnectionProfileManager.<init>(ConnectionProfile.java:138)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.activities.SelectConnectionProfile.fillData(SelectConnectionProfile.java:71)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.caumons.trainingdininghall.activities.SelectConnectionProfile.onResume(SelectConnectionProfile.java:66)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3833)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1643)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2796)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:932)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-26 12:54:21.839: E/Database(3925):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I coded the following workaround, but I think this is not very polite:

```
private void openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport() {
    try {
        mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        mDatabase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        /*
         * If there is an exception because the database is locked,
         * we will retry until it is free and can be opened.
         * */
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
        openReadableDatabaseWithForeignKeySupport(); // Recursive call
    }
}
```

The most curious is that what seems to fail is the `setLocale()` method called automatically by Android, but the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLocale%28java.util.Locale%29) says that:

> setLocale() Sets the locale for this database. Does nothing if this database has the NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS flag set or was opened read only.

Any help will be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Check this Question, you may find help: [SQLite exception: Database is locked issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657223/sqlite-exception-database-is-locked-issue)

Comment: Also, to keep from recreating your activity when it is rotated, you can add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" to your activity definition in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a great idea to be opening and closing the database regularly like this. Open it once on application startup, and reuse this connection throughout your app's lifetime. You don't even need to bother closing it. SQLite manages the concurrency by itself, so you don't need to worry about multiple threads either.

This will make all your "database is locked" errors go away, as well as make your code tidier and simpler.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the fast answer! :) So, you would create a singleton to hold your Database, am I right? Isn't it a bad practice not closing the database?

Comment: I have already implemented this and worked well. However, I have one doubt... should I synchronize the singleton instance or it is not needed (as it is actually not modified itself)? Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: No need to synchronize, and no need to close the database. All database writes are committed to storage at the earliest opportunity anyway, so closing it gives no benefit.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! :) Just one more thing... is it really necessary to close the cursors even if you are not noticing any warnings in the logcat?

Comment: You should close cursors. Otherwise you'll just be leaking memory and resources.

Comment: I thought that if they are local to a method they would be automatically garbage collected and there was no need to call `close()` explicitly... Am I wrong with this? Do these cursors still remain in memory after the code of the scope they belong to has fully been executed?

Comment: Garbage collection can reclaim the memory occupied by the Java Cursor objects, but the Cursor may need to do additional cleanup, such as telling the underlying database that it has been closed, etc. This is why it has a `close()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This completely clarifies my doubt! :)