# NullPointerException - Database locked issue while retrieving data from database and storing into an array

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve a list of dates(in string format) from a PersonDOB column in database. Then I am encountering Database locked issue. I have declared open() and close() methods for the database. Even though I am getting these errors. I am unable to understand, why I am getting this error.
I have read some articles like

[Question - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657223/sqlite-exception-database-is-locked-issue)

[Question - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930139/android-database-locked)

Not only these, I have tried solutions given in other questions and articles also. But I am unable to get an appropriate solution, that suits my context.
In my entire code, I am using the write operation only once. So, there is no problem of data corruption.
 Here is the code, where I am getting data from the database.

```
public String[] getDataInArray() { // get data for list and return in array form
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase myDB;
        String[] return_columns;
         try {

              myDB=this.openDataBase();       
              String DOB = "PersonDOB";
            String[] columms = new String[]{ DOB };



            Cursor c = myDB.query("Persons", columms, null, null, null, null, null);

            int iDOB = c.getColumnIndex(DOB);

            int rowcount = 0;
              return_columns = new String[c.getCount()];
            for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
            {
                return_columns[rowcount] = c.getString(iDOB);
                rowcount = rowcount + 1;
            }



                  if(c != null)
                 {
                     myDB.close();
                     c.close();
                  }          


                  }catch(SQLException sqle){

                  throw sqle;

                  }
         for (int i = 0;i<return_columns.length;i++)
            {
                                     Log.v("DOB", return_columns[i]); //I am not
 getting this log message in the logcat.
            }
        return return_columns;
        }
```

And I get the following errors in the logcat -

```
09-19 15:58:00.140: W/System.err(7115): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 15:58:00.140: W/System.err(7115):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
09-19 15:58:00.140: W/System.err(7115):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
09-19 15:58:00.200: W/System.err(7115):     at com.example.fromstart.adapter.open(adapter.java:30)
09-19 15:58:00.210: W/System.err(7115):     at com.example.fromstart.adapter.getDataInArray(adapter.java:222)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your problem but in case your cursor is null, the database is never closed. Try try to move myDB.close() below the if(c !=null)

Comment: ok @UngureanuLiviu, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing database `myDB.close();` is not enough to avoid locks. You need to close the `cursors` which you are using for `database` operations before closing the database or when the operation with the cursor is completed. If you are using `Thread`s please make sure they also must be properly closed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Avadhani Y, I have now closed the cursor also. Please see my updated code. But I am getting the same error in the log.

Comment: @nki how can u close cursor after database is closed? Place `c.close()` before `myDB.close()`

Comment: I have made the change as you said. But also getting the same error. I have placed `c.close();` before `myDB.close();`. That worked for me at that time.

Comment: Do you know, what might be the other reasons, to get this error?

Comment: The chances would be not properly closing the `threads`, `cursors`, `database objects`,... Please refer this document: http://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html