# Android cannot open database with multiple tables

Tags: android

I'm new on android and I understand almost everything except this
when I use my code to open and read my db with just one table it works, but when I tried to change my db to another with more tables using the same code just don't works, logcat says "cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]"

I used the tutorial [using your own sqlite database in android applications](http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to create my DataBaseHelper

```
package com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Scarieg on 09/08/2016.
 */
public class BDD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "db_tables.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    private final static int Version = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";


    public BDD(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, Version);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    (SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS));

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,(SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS));

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    public Cursor Read(String COLUMN, String Table) {
        //includes all column names
        String COLUMN_KEY = COLUMN;
        String DATABASE_TABLE = Table;
        try {

            openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }
        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT "+KEY_ROWID+", "+COLUMN_KEY+" FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.
}
```

ande here is how I call it

```
package com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Scarieg on 03/08/2016.
 */
public class IdiomalistFragment extends Fragment {

    View myView;
    public BDD myDbHelper = new BDD(getActivity());
    public String t;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.idiomalist,container,false);
        ListView frases = (ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.lv_frases);


        Bundle b = getArguments();
        t = b.getString("Idioma");
        TextView Idioma = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.Idioma_TV);
        Idioma.setText(t);
        try
        {myDbHelper.createDataBase();}
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {throw new Error("Unable to create database");}

        try
        {myDbHelper.openDataBase();}
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {throw sqle;}




        String[] from = new String[]{"Frase"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text};
        Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.Read("Frase", t);
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, cursor, from, to, 1);
        frases.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        frases.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });

        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        final Spinner spinner_cat = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCat);
        String[] from_cat = new String[]{"Categoria"};
        int[] to_cat = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        final Cursor c_cat = myDbHelper.Read("Categoria", t);
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c_cat, from_cat, to_cat, 1);
        mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_cat.setPrompt("Selecciona Una Categoria");

        spinner_cat.setAdapter(
                new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(mAdapter,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                        getActivity()));

        spinner_cat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                if (i!=0) {
                    Cursor c = (Cursor) spinner_cat.getSelectedItem();
                    String Cat = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Categoria"));
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("Categoria", Cat);
                    FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    CategoriaFragment mFrag = new CategoriaFragment();
                    mFrag.setArguments(args);
                    t.replace(R.id.content_frame, mFrag);
                    t.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).show(mFrag);
                    t.addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

and this is the logcat

```
08-16 18:36:45.652 26369-26369/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
08-16 18:36:45.652 26369-26369/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
08-16 18:36:45.652 26369-26369/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/data/data/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas/databases/db_tables.db) - 
08-16 18:36:45.652 26369-26369/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas/databases/db_tables.db'.
                                                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
                                                                                   at com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas.BDD.checkDataBase(BDD.java:64)
                                                                                   at com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas.BDD.createDataBase(BDD.java:36)
                                                                                   at com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas.IdiomalistFragment.onCreateView(IdiomalistFragment.java:44)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
                                                                                   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 18:36:45.652 26369-26369/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-16 18:36:45.652 26369-26369/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62b4288)
08-16 18:36:45.656 26369-26369/com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
                                                                                   at com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas.BDD.createDataBase(BDD.java:44)
                                                                                   at com.cele.nd.frasesidiomaticas.IdiomalistFragment.onCreateView(IdiomalistFragment.java:44)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
                                                                                   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
                                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope someone help me out and thanks in advance

Comment: What is line IdiomalistFragment.java:44. Initially it seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892350/nullpointerexception-database-locked-issue-while-retrieving-data-from-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error log points to a `NullPointerException` - I am suspecting that this has to do with how you initialize your db-helper (`BDD`). You need to change and move the line `public BDD myDbHelper = new BDD(getActivity());`.
My suggestion is that you change the declaration to

```
private BDD myDbHelper;
```

Then you need to add `onActivityCreated` method and then declare `BDD` there. Here is the code you can just plug in:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myDbHelper = new BDD(getActivity());
}
```

I am suspecting the `getActivity()` method the way you had it might have caused the null value to be passed, and thereby causing `NullPointerException`.

I hope the suggestion helps.

Comment: it works D: thanks, think I have to study that part because I don't really understand very well the solution, thanks again

Comment: I am glad this helped you. Happy coding.